# Prove that if a subset $A$ of a metric space is bounded then the closure of $A$ is bounded and diam(A) is equal to the diam(cl(A)).

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove that if a subset $A$ of a metric space is bounded then the closure of $A$ is bounded and the diameter of $A$ is equal to the diameter of the closure of $A$.

This is the question I am working on at the moment. I think I have proven that cl(A) is bounded as follows:

If A is bounded then $\exists x_0 \in X$ and $K$ constant s.t. $d(x_0,x)\leq K$  $\forall x\in X$.

Let $a \in$ cl(A), then $B_\epsilon (a) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$.

Now let $a'\in B_\epsilon (a) \cap A$, then $d(a,x_0)\leq d(a,a')+d(a',x_0)\leq \epsilon +K$.

As this is true $\forall \epsilon > 0$ this means $d(a, x_0) \leq K$ and cl(A) is hence bounded.

So now I need to show that diam(A) = diam(cl(A)).

The diameter is defined as diam(A) = sup($d(x,y)$) $\forall x,y \in A$.

I want to do this by letting $K$ be the least upper bound of A and then I would like to just say that as both A and cl(A) are bounded by the same thing, the supremum of the distance between any two points in either A or cl(A), which is $K$, is equal to diam(A) and diam(cl(A)).  Is this the correct or right way to go about it?

Comment: I would encourage you to write down your proof with proper mathematical sentences, ideally with the whole $\epsilon, \delta, \exists, \forall$ verbiage. This will tell you immediately if your idea works or not. Plain english "proofs" tend to hide away the complex details and to be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is bounded, for some $r > 0$, any two points in $A$ are at a maximum distance  $\leq r$ from each other. Fix arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Then any point of $\bar A$ is at a distance $< \epsilon$ from some point of $A$. Using triangle inequality any two points of $\bar A$ are at a distance $< r + 2\epsilon$ from each other hence $\bar A$ is bounded. Moreover the diameter is less than $r + 2\epsilon$. But since the $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the diameter is $\leq r$. And it is exactly $r$ because $A \subseteq \bar A$ and diameter of $A$ is $r$.

Comment: @MW I know that I had confused things a little bit. I think $\leq r$ in the answer should fix that.

Comment: Yeah I think I exaggerated the problem anyway, think the only actual problematic strict inequality was the second one, which you fixed.  Looks good now.

Comment: It was error so thanks for pointing out. Precision should always be there. This time it was still right with minor fixing but sometimes it may not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of a proof:

- $D = \text{diam}(A) \le D' = \text{diam}(\bar A)$

  - by def. of $D$, there are sequences $x_n,y_n$ in $A$ with $d(x_n,y_n) \to D$
  - since $A$ is metric and bounded, it satisfies BW, so you can assume $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, with (by def. of $\bar A$), $x,y \in \bar A$)
  - conclude using continuity of $d$
- $D' \le D$

  - take $\epsilon > 0$ and try to prove $D' \le D+\epsilon$ using arguments similar to the one above

Comment: Bounded and closed does not imply compact, even in the metric setting (consider your favourite orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$).

Comment: The first point is much simpler. As $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ we get $$ \text{diam}(A) = \sup_{x,y\in A} d(x,y) \leq \sup_{x,y\in \overline{A}} d(x,y) = \text{diam}(\overline{A}).$$ For the second part, pick $(x_n)_n, (y_n)_n \subseteq \overline{A}$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow \text{diam}(\overline{A})$. By definition of the closure, we can find $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n \subseteq A$ such that $d(a_n, x_n) \rightarrow 0, d(b_n, y_n) \rightarrow 0$. Thus, $d(a_n, b_n)\rightarrow \text{diam}(\overline{A})$, which implies $\text{diam}(A)\geq \text{diam}(\overline{A})$.